# Failsafe disposal in an async world

Tags: c#, idisposable

In the synchronous world, C# makes the management of all things disposable really rather easy:

```
using(IDisposable someDisposable=bla.bla())
{
     //do our bidding
}
//don't worry too much about it
```

However, when we go async, we no longer have the convenience of the `using` block. One of the best strategies I've encountered is the [CCR iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648753.aspx) which allows us to use async code "as if it were synchronous". This means we can keep our `using` block in the iterator handler and not get too bogged down in the complex decision of when to dispose and catching all the cases where disposal is required.

However, in many cases, invoking CCR can seem like overkill, and to be honest, although I'm quite comfortable with CCR, to the uninitiated it can look like double-dutch.

So my question is: what other strategies exist for the management of one's IDisposable's, when the disposable objects must persist beyond the immediate scope?

Comment: Good question. I'm only posting this comment so I can find it again.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Doesn't it make more sense to "favorite" the question to make it easy to find?

Comment: @Gabe: how am I supposed to remember to go look at my favorites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this problem was also on the minds of the language designers.

The correct answer to this question is now to use the `Task` based versions of the asynchronous APIs that have been provided for almost all asynchronous operations, coupled with the new C# `async`/`await` keywords. These allow us to keep everything in scope over the lifetime of asynchronous operations:

```
async Task<int> DoSomething()
{
    using(var foo = new SomeDisposableThing())
    {
         await foo.DoSomethingAsync();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to have all methods that would not be able to coexist with the disposal method take a lock while they run, and check a queue for objects needing disposal when they finish.  The disposal method could then add itself to the queue, use TryEnter to try to acquire the lock, dispose the object and delete it from the queue if successful, or else let the current holder of the lock handle the disposal.

Comment: What about callbacks?  The code that has to complete before disposal might not even be run until some other event happens.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I'm assuming one knows when a particular item will no longer be needed.  What makes asynchronous dispose tricky is not the possibility of simultaneous or pending operations with the object being disposed, but rather simultaneous operations on entities that will be affected by the dispose.  Suppose, for example, one has a database that uses a single data stream for communication; different connections are assigned ID numbers, and each command or response includes the connection ID.  If a command is being sent when a thread wants to close a connection...

Comment: @Ben Voigt: ...the "close" command would have to wait.  Depending upon circumstances, it might be good for the Dispose to wait until the close is done so one will know whether it worked, but if that could take awhile, it might be better for Dispose to enqueue the close command and return immediately.  The point is that what matters isn't multiple threads using the connection object, but rather multiple threads using the data stream.